# If the odds of something occuring are $5/68$, given $36$ attempts, how can I calculate the odds of it occuring $x$ number of times?

Tags: probability

> If the odds of something occurring are $5/68$, given $36$ attempts, how can I calculate the odds of it occurring $x$ number of times?

Basically is there a general form equation for this kind of calculation?

#### Background

I heard of the binomial distribution, probably in high school or something but it's been a while. Wikipedia was somewhat helpful but I can't figure out how to make a generic equation out of what it's telling me.

Comment: Have you heard of the binomial distribution?

Comment: Probably in high school or something but it's been a while. Wikipedia was somewhat helpful but I can't figure out how to make a generic equation out of what it's telling me.

Comment: Despite getting 'a general form equation', or maybe even before that, you should check carefully what is 'odds' in your question and how it is related to 'probability' (because most sources will give you equations about probabilities rather than odds). See e.g. [this post on MathForum.org](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56706.html) or [this article on Math-Magic.com](http://www.math-magic.com/probability/prob_to_odds.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Bernoulli's Formula (in binomial distribution): the probability of something with probability (in one single try) $\;p\;$ happening $\;k\;$ times in $\;n\;,\;\;n\ge k\;$ ,
 tries is

$$P_n(k):=\binom nk p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

with

$$\binom nk:=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Comment: Yeah that's basically what Wikipedia told me, but I don't understand the notation. Is the n!/k!(n-k)! part the full equation?

Comment: Yes, of course. That's the definition of the binomial coefficient. If you don't know what a factorial is then you may want first to study a little of this.